# Facebook share button doesnt open dialog in real android devices

Tags: android, facebook, share

I am using facebook ShareButton in my android app. The application try to share a text in facebook. My app succesfully login with facebook. Hash keys and APP key in manifest file is correct I checked.

```
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23"
```

I am using viewpager with nested fragments. I am setting share button in facebook with following function and I have defined a custom button for checkin, when user clicks check in, I am performing a click on facebook share button. This senario, succesfully works in emulator, share button opens a login dialog when user loggin with different provider than shares. If user log in with facebook, It opens directly the share dialog. But in real devices, button click doesnt open a share dialog, but it tries a little screen effect, but nothing appears, only the current fragment showing. But screen become disable (like something else is on screen),  when I press the back button, application goes actual state and current fragment become functional. I have search through internet but I cannot find a solution. Anybody have an idea.

```
  checkinButtonAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isFacebook &&  facebookEnable.isChecked())
            {
                // Create an object
                ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                        .putString("og:type", "restaurant.restaurant")
                        .putString("og:title", ((MainActivity) getActivity()).clickedRestaurantName)
                        .putString("og:description", uc.formCheckinText())
                        .build();
                // Create an action
                ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                        .setActionType("restaurant.visited")
                        .putObject("restaurant", object)
                        .build();
                // Create the content
                ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                        .setPreviewPropertyName("restaurant")
                        .setAction(action)
                        .build();
                facebookCheckinButton.setShareContent(content);
               facebookCheckinButton.performClick();
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is becausse of the facebook app submission process. In the developer mode, you are requesting permissions from the user and facebook does not want anything other than that. But when you put your app in the google play (even if closed beta test), in facebook, you must publish your app and follow the steps to get permissions you need. For example, for publishing an action on facebook, you have get publish_action permission and to get the permission, facebook require screenshots and screencasts from you. You have to complete the steps and submit a version in the "App Review" part of your fb developer console.